# PHP foreach loop, calculate aggregate sum of employees total pay

Tags: php, foreach

I am using a foreach loop in PHP. Loop populates number of employees, most of these employees repeat their self within the loop.

I want a way, to show SUM of employees pay, until next employee occurs.

Result will be like.

```
Employee    Pay
A           10
A            5
Total       15
B            7
B            8
Total        15
```

and so on.

my array is like! :

```
$result = [

      'A' => 12,
      'B' => 10,
      'A' => 7,
      'B' => 20,
      'C' => 11
];
```

My code is like this.

```
<?php foreach($result as $results){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $results['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $results['pay'] ?></td>
</tr>
// I want show total here, like I said above.
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: Please show your array here

Comment: what  your array exactly looks like?

Comment: Operators like `+` and `=` should be helpful here.  Have you tried those?

Comment: I am not able to accomplish this. Let me add my code snippet here.

Comment: Start by applying an ORDER BY to your SQL query so that the rows with the same name occur after each other (`ORDER BY name`)

Comment: Are you sure your array looks like this? have you tried `var_dump($result);` and see what is inside your array? from the code you provided, you think there should be 5 rows in your array, but in real world, there are only 3 rows! `'A' => 7` will overwrite `'A' => 12`  and `'B' => 20` will also overwrite `'B' => 10`. So please edit your answer and add the correct format of your array.

Answer (score 0):

The point of array is to have unique keys.

so your array should be like this:

```
$result = [
   'A' => [ 12,  7],
   'B' => [ 10, 20],  
   'C' =>[11]
];
```

Then you can simply do:

```
foreach($result as $value => $key){
    echo $value . ":" . array_sum($key) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

and the result will be :

```
A : 19
B : 30
C : 11
```

Comment: You've answer the question base on what you think his array should look like. But the question is how he can achieve what he wants to with the current structure of his array!

Comment: you are right, but having such array is not allowed in php, so i suggested a valid array!

Comment: Actually php lets you create this array without any errors but the content will not be as the OP described as I mentioned in my comment under the question. When you create this array `$result = ['A' => 12, 'B' => 10, 'A' => 7, 'B' => 20, 'C' => 11];`, it will automatically become like this: `$result = ['A' => 7, 'B' => 20, 'C' => 11];` because 7 will be overwritten on key `A` and 20 will be overwritten on key `B`. So I think his array structure is something else. If he has his array from a DB query, then probably he has a nested array which first he has to elaborate more on his question.

Comment: yes, you are right! thanks. It seems he is not interested to any answer anymore!! ;))

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki you suggested edit for the question, and now you are saying the array is wrong. I totally agree the array is wrong. I am new to stack, so I was not able to skip your edit as it was saying you need some reputation to do that.

Comment: Anyways the array is an associative array. I will update my array structure.

Comment: ok , what is your array exactly?! comment here if you can not edit